# BigQuery - filter data by values present in a second table

Tags: mysql, google-bigquery

I need to filter Google Analytics data, from one table, filtered by data which is present in a second table.

The query I am using is as follows:

```
SELECT 
fullvisitorid,visitNumber,

max(case when hits.customdimensions.index = 30 then 
hits.customdimensions.value end) login_id

FROM [table_1]
GROUP EACH BY fullvisitorid,visitNumber
```

I have a second table, table_2, that contains a list of login_ids which are of particular interest (and which are only a small fraction of those in table_1).
What I'd like to do is filter the data from table_1 by the login_id contained in table_2, so only those login_ids are returned when I query table_1.
All help gratefully appreciated.

EDIT:

The above query returns a table which looks like this (data from table_1):

```
Row fullvisitorid       visitNumber  login_id    
10  8812091098272426348    1         
11  8812203501855327426    3         
12  8813941868399328770    15        
13  8814004579217219789    1         
14  8814073006630329047    102       6kena7aeq1sc312porfhyf  
15  8814073006630329047    103       6kena7aeq1sc312porfhyf  
16  8814200803368464684    257       
17  8814344603188097744    1         
18  8814410578161636902    94
```

Table_2 looks like this:

```
Row login_id     
1   user_id  
2   00015mY5EVDsSgFlDDq3EU   
3   006rcSwDU1r8fiGnCIBCOZ   
4   008ZM8TeCwo3V8Lcyip3rT   
5   008nzvMgSF4Ir94ja04lXl   
6   00DFrm85sK0tDUm96Kedkw   
7   00GLa0WE0sq1Np4bvtmL9j
```

When I test the following, I get an error message which says 'cannot partition on repeated field hits.customdimensions.value'. I suspect the use of case/end may be messing things up.

```
SELECT 
fullvisitorid,visitNumber,

max(case when hits.customdimensions.index = 30 then 
hits.customdimensions.value end) as login_id

FROM [table_1] as t1
inner join [table_2] as t2 on t2.login_id 
= t1.hits.customdimensions.value

GROUP EACH BY fullvisitorid,visitNumber
```

Any help gratefully appreciated. The desired outcome is that only the data from table_1, where the login_ids match those of table_2 is returned.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below (it is for BigQuery Legacy SQL as it is what your question is in)

```sql
#legacySQL
SELECT
  fullvisitorid, 
  visitNumber,
  t2.login_id AS login_id
FROM (
  SELECT 
    fullvisitorid, 
    visitNumber,
    MAX(CASE WHEN hits.customdimensions.index = 30 
      THEN hits.customdimensions.value END
    ) AS login_id
  FROM [table_1]
  GROUP BY fullvisitorid, visitNumber
) AS t1
JOIN [table_2] AS t2
ON t2.login_id = t1.login_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select 
    t1.fullvisitorid,
    t1.visitNumber
FROM        
    (SELECT 
    fullvisitorid,visitNumber,

    max(case when hits.customdimensions.index = 30 then 
    hits.customdimensions.value end) login_id

    FROM [table_1]) as t1
inner join [table_2] as t2 on t2.login_id = t1.login_id
GROUP EACH BY fullvisitorid,visitNumber
```

or probably it should be

```
 inner join [table_2] as t2 on t2.login_id = t1.hits.customdimensions.value
```

anyways inner join is the solution you need.

Comment: Thanks for the help, and it feels like I'm getting somewhere; but now it throws up a 'Cannot join on repeated field hits.customDimensions.value'. Any thoughts?

Comment: Hm, actually you can try joining with subquery (updated the answer). Possibly you'll need to move GROUP EACH BY also to subquery